# Hugin don't start (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, image-processing

I write `hugin` in terminal windows and it send me :

```
hugin: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5: symbol lzma_lzma_prese4, version XZ_5.0 not defined in file liblzma.so.5 with link time reference
```

Do you have any idea of what I have to do to launch hugin ?
Many thanks

Comment: Have you installed `hugin` using apt and the official 16.04 repositories? I am asking as i can't reproduce that problem on my 16.04 install.

Comment: Yes. I installed it with 'Logiciels Ubuntu 3.20.1' ('Ubuntu software' in English)

Comment: So you haven't just installed it as most users would expect by running: `sudo apt-get install hugin` but instead using some software called `Logiciels`?

Comment: Thank you ! I removed my first install from the official Ubuntu Software center and reinstalled it by the terminal and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments the solution was as follows:

- Removing the formerly installed hugin
- Install hugin via default sources (`sudo apt-get install hugin`)